# Glide holds java heap even if all activities are finished

Tags: android, android-glide

After finishing all my activities and triggering GC, my java heap takes about 26M of memory. Then, I take a look at of it and find that Glide holds a significant size of it.Does anyone know how to solve it?[image]

Comment: I am not certain what you think needs to be solved. Process-level caches live as long as the process does. If you wanted to override `onTrimMemory()` somewhere (e.g., a custom `Application` subclass) and reduce your heap usage at that point, [Glide appears to have a `clearMemory()` method for that](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#clearing-memory).

Comment: `how to solve it?` it doesn't need to be solved as it is expected behavior and is not a problem

Comment: Use it this way Glide.with(mContext).load("IMAGE_URL").diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(Image_View);

Comment: @CommonsWare thx for ur answer. My company has set a limit of 20M to the java heap。So I have to solve it。As to         Glide.get(this).clearMemory(); I have invoked it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then adjust the Glide cache size: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#memory-cache